# N-Pulse Oscillator

Tags: oscillator, flipflop, counter, frequency-divider

I want to build a circuit which, each time a button is pressed, outputs 'N' pulses from an oscillator. I'm working on a solution which uses a flip-flop to control a switch at the output of the oscillator. The flip-flop is set by the button, and reset by a divide by N counter. Although this sounds like it would be a pretty clean solution, some timing issues and other minutia have made it become pretty messy and makes me wonder if there's a more elegant solution.

Do you know if there's a simple way to accomplish this?

---

I didn't want to add too many details about my specific circuit because I'm more curious about how this type of problem is addressed broadly rather than how to build one specific circuit or fix my approach. But I see why more details would help so here they are:

- The frequency I'm using is 4 MHz
- My value for N is 18

Here's my circuit (with annotations):
[image]

Lastly, my question is different from [How to construct a discrete circuit to send out a square wave with N pulses?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/461515/how-to-construct-a-discrete-circuit-to-send-out-a-square-wave-with-n-pulses) because I'm not imposing the limit of avoiding 'complex' elements like ICs and would prefer to use them if they allow a cleaner solution. I'm hoping to find the simplest and most reliable way to generate 'N' pulses.

Comment: Show us a schematic of what you're doing, it may be a simple fix.

Comment: You should include the frequency you need/want to operate at as that would be a metric for difficulty level.

Comment: What is the range of N desired? What frequency?

Comment: The simple solution is an MCU controlling an internal counter/timer peripheral.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to construct a discrete circuit to send out a square wave with N pulses?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/461515/how-to-construct-a-discrete-circuit-to-send-out-a-square-wave-with-n-pulses)